# Renting a car in Tel Aviv as a young driver with a new license?

Tags: car-rentals, driving-licenses, israel, age-limits, tel-aviv

I plan to get a driver's license in February and then visit Israel in May. It would be nice to rent a car somewhere in Tel Aviv as that's the most convenient way of sightseeing the country. However I wasn't able to find a car rental that accepts both:

- Drivers aged 23
- Drivers who were issued their license earlier than 1 year ago

It would be acceptable to pick up the car anywhere in the Tel Aviv area (and Ben Gurion airport).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question, but please note that drop-off of rental cars in Tel Aviv may be a bit less convenient than you're used to.  My experience was the hours are limited and the lots are physically blocked to prevent return outside of those hours.  Return to the airport should be easy though.

Comment: Chances for this stuff are now. Insurance premiums go up dramatically for young/inexperienced drivers, so normally the agencies don't allow those.

Comment: At least in Prague there's a company which rents out to drivers aged over 18 without a surcharge, while Hertz and other big guys ask for 2 years of experience.

Comment: Road conditions and driving in Prague is a little different to in Tel Aviv...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is hard. The insurance prices go considerably up for drivers younger than 24, and for new drivers. From looking online it seems that the big rental companies will not rent out cars to people younger than 24 or who have had a driver's license for less than 2 years.

I was able to find at least 3 smaller companies who will rent cars to new (and young) drivers for a higher rate.

- [Aviv Car Rentals](http://www.aviv-rent.co.il/%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9)
- [Auto Gold](http://www.dsite.co.il/auto/car_rental.asp?Title=%E4%F9%EB%F8%FA%20%F8%EB%E1%20-%20%E2%ED%20%EC%F6%F2%E9%F8%E9%ED)
- [Best Car](http://www.best-car.co.il/Article.aspx?articleId=144)

I have seen that there are other companies which rent to new drivers, discussed in various forums, you should google for "השכרת רכב לנהג חדש" (car rental for a new driver) and "השכרת רכב לנהג צעיר" (car rental for a young driver). Knowing Hebrew would come a long way to help you read the forum posts, or you could try and rely on Google Translate.

Comment: thanks! I've contacted a couple of agencies for exact pricing and would post the results here.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the small rental agencies responded to my emails. I think it's best to just stick to buses for this trip :)

Comment: You could try and call them.